# Как вклиниться в Thread?

Tags: c#, .net

Я как то встречал возможность выполнить код, вклинившись в работающий `Thread`. Но не могу вспомнить как это делалось. Суть та же что и для `Dispatcher.Invoke()` или `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`, но для `Thread`

Comment: А что значит "выполнить код, вклинившись в работающий Thread"?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я ведь привел пример на основе Dispatcher. То есть мне нужно в уже существующем и рабочем thread выполнить мой Action, с возможностью выполнить немедленно или дождаться, пока поток закончит текущую задачу.

Comment: Для справки, "Вклиниться" можно только в поток, имеющий очередь сообщений.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843010/net-how-do-i-invoke-a-delegate-on-a-specific-thread-isynchronizeinvoke-disp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод  `Init()` не завершится, пока не будет вызван `BeginInvokeShutdown();`

```
private void Init()  
{     
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoWork));     
    workerThread.IsBackground = true;     
    workerThread.Start(Dispatcher.Current);                 


    Dispatcher.Run();  

    // Once shutdown you cannot restart the dispatcher in this appdomain  
}    

void DoWork(object startArg) 
{  
    Dispatcher targetDispatcher = startArg as Dispatcher;  
    if(targetDispatcher == null) {  
       // Log error  
       return;  
    }  

    while(working)   
    {  
       targetDispatcher.BeginInvoke(....);  
    }  

    targetDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(...);  
}
```